# change variable php with jquery and ajax

Tags: php

I've read several posts on this issue but I can't seem to make it work the way I would like. 
Basically I would like to skip an if statement when the page is reloaded from a certain link.

here is a simplified version of my code. I believe using isset($post  would be the way to go.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    $num_parent_cat = 1 -> (change this variable on reload)

     if ($num_parent_cat == 1){

   <a href="CLICK THIS LINK?>" </a>
}

else{ GET HERE AFTER RELOADING PAGE FROM LINK}
```

Comment: can you explain how is ajax part of this problem?

Comment: I'm pretty new to programming but I believe since php is server side you would need to use ajax to reload the page to change the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code doesn't show any research, but...

```
if(isset($_POST['something']) && $_POST['something'] === 1){
    echo "All Done";
} else {
?>

<form method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="something" value="1">
   <input type="submit" value="click here">
</form>

<?php
}
```

This is example, mind you I haven't used `PHP` in months and this is not tested, but should work

So basically what's happening here is, the `isset($_POST['something'])` is checking that there is a `POST` variable set called `something` then if it is set it will check that is is equal to `1` if so, then `echo "All Done"` else serve a form that when submitted will send a `POST` variable `something` to the same page with a value of `1`

Comment: Thanks Connor that worked great. From what I gather you used isset to make sure the variable is declared and then $post to pass the data in a form.

Answer (score 0):

Links don't post anything unless you add some serious Javascripting going on. 
Usually a page like this doesn't have a link but a form. If you have an HTML form in your page, you can add a submit button (which may be styled as a link). The form can post data or send it in the url. The PHP script that is executed can detect those values.

Another solution is to add a parameter in the url of the link:

```
if (array_key_exists('via', $_GET) && $_GET['via'] == 'linkX')
{
   <a href="yourpage.php?via=linkX">Click me</a>
}
else
{
  echo 'It worked!';
}
```

Note, though, that anyone could just add this value to the url to fool your script into thinking that the link was clicked.